# Lenovo notebook z580 impossible to launch bios setup

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

On Lenovo z580 I launch the laptop by pressing the special Lenovo Novo menu button there comes blue Novo button menu where I select BIOS Setup and computer continues to boot without showing bios setup. Is that a faulty laptop?

Edit: there is an empty hd without os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method:

1. Start the machine, all to get running.
2. Restart. This is slower than cold start.
3. Watch for the screen message  "Press enter to access setup"
4. Press the enter key and BIOS should start.

Another method:

[Access Lenovo BIOS](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-z-series-laptops/ideapad-z580/solutions/ht500216-recommended-way-to-enter-bios-ideapad)

> To enter BIOS via function key
>
> Turn the PC off.
>
> Turn the PC on.
>
> The PC screen displays the Lenovo logo.
>
> Immediately and repeatedly press (Fn+) F2 or F2. **Accessing the BIOS
> may take multiple attempts.**

I have used both methods successfully.

If still no luck, contact Lenovo Support.

**Followup note:**  @Vojtěch Dohnal said that the drive is dead.  A new drive can be procured and in the the case of Windows 10 the operating system can be installed with the recovery USB that Lenovo can supply. The recovery will build all partitions needed including the UEFI partition. Access to BIOS is not needed to do re-install the disk.

I suggest this approach.

Comment: Thanks, but the disk is dead and restart is not an option.

Comment: So then contact Lenovo Support about replacing the disk and starting BIOS.

Comment: Could bios be stored on the hard disk, is that possible?

Comment: You can use the Lenovo recovery USB and that will re-create the UEFI partition.

Comment: Is that safe to do it on a disk with a fresh win 10 installation?

Comment: Yes it is. I have done this before.  The machine will re-activate upon installation.

Comment: Lenovo is weird, I cannot boot from USB or CD unless I remove HDD. I will let it be already, but probably you are right. Very bad software made by Lenovo indeed.